# How to connect on-preemies Kafka through Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Want to connect on-premise Kafka through Azure data factory to access messages and stored to adls.

Connect to kafka by using ADF

My data is available in on-premise kafka , want to access and load to adls.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your on-prem Kafka is not accessible via the public internet, you have two options. You can either connect via a Managed Virtual Network (also referred to as a Managed Private Endpoint) or a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime.

Here's some explanations I copied from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/choose-the-right-integration-runtime-configuration.

**Azure integration runtime with managed virtual network**

When using the Azure integration runtime with a managed virtual network, you should use managed private endpoints to connect your data sources to ensure data security during transmission. With some additional settings such as Private Link Service and Load Balancer, managed private endpoints can also be used to access on-premises data sources.

**Self-hosted integration runtime**

To prevent data from different environments from interfering with each other and ensure the security of the production environment, we need to create a corresponding self-hosted integration runtime for each environment. This ensures sufficient isolation between different environments.

Since the self-hosted integration runtime runs on a customer managed machine, in order to reduce the cost, maintenance, and upgrade efforts as much as possible, we can make use of the shared functions of the self-hosted integration runtime for different projects in the same environment. For details on self-hosted integration runtime sharing, refer to the article Create a shared self-hosted integration runtime in Azure Data Factory. At the same time, to make the data more secure during transmission, we can choose to use a private link to connect the data sources and key vault, and connect the communication between the self-hosted integration runtime and the Azure Data Factory service.